# What type of capacitor is this?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, circuit-design

I'm not quite sure if I'm understanding this right.  I had a circuit (which I can't share) given me.  In the parts list one of the components is "10nF ceramic, 0.1” pitch leads " (this parts list is very old maybe 2005.)  Is this capacitor a ceramic disc or MLCC leaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If something from 2005 is very old, I start to feel ancient*...

Given the scant specification, the component is likely non-critical. I'd avoid class III dielectrics, which should be avoided like the plague anyway, and choose any class II (e.g. the common X7R) MLCC with that capacitance and that pitch.

Comment: are disc capacitor is no longer use and replaced by mlcc ?

Comment: @Settasak They have much larger volume, and I doubt you can find a 10 nF disc capacitor with that pitch. And if there is, it's likely a class III dielectric, which has very poor dielectric properties.

Comment: i had to redesign this pcb anyway so i will go with mlcc, thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/C315C103K5R5TA/817924

[image]

I went to digikey.com and searched for capacitors.  ceramic, through hole, lead spacing 0.1" and found many many options.

Comment: I've been googling for the past hours but i'm not quite sure for the type, when i try searcing with that word it either give me mlcc leaded or disc ,but answer from Massimo Ortolano is clear and i understand now, thank you